# Fiberglass vs wood door

Tags: wood, doors, woodworking, carpentry, fiberglass

How can I tell if my door is made out of fiberglass or wood? It has a wood grain texture but I can’t tell if it’s a real wood door or a fiberglass door.

Answer (score 2):

Open the door. Get on a ladder and look at the top.  If you can see end grain of the wood, you know it's wood.

Comment: A solid wood door will show end-grain on the stiles (the vertical parts of the door at both the hinge & lock sides) and long grain in the middle (at the rail). If you see long grain all (or almost all) the way across or no grain at all, then that's the solid bit at the edges to give the screws for the hinges and lock to bite into.